# Is there a way to add plain html inside an Asp.Net multiview control?

Tags: asp.net, multiview

I have a page with several stepped panels using a multiview control. We're changing the page slighlty which means that all headers will always be on display, but the content will be shown/hidden by the multiview.

Here's what the html would look like:

```
<asp:MultView ID= "MultiView1" runat= "server">
   <h2>Title 1</h2>
   <asp:View ID= "View1" runat= "server"> </asp:View>
   <h2>Title 2</h2>
   <asp:View ID= "View2" runat= "server"> </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Unfortunately, the plain html is not rendered so the headers never get seen. Just wondering if there is a way round this as I don't want to lose the convenience of the multiview control.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the view's can be added html

```
 <asp:View ID= "View1" runat= "server"> <h2>Title 1</h2></asp:View>
```

Or you can try and inject html with asp:PlaceHolder not sure it will work...

Comment: Just so long as the control can be [found](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h(v=vs.110).aspx) the `PlaceHolder` should also work.

Comment: This solution won't work - h2 are always visible, mv content is selectively visible but must reside between the h2's - placeholder may be an option..

Comment: Placeholder doen't work either - sometimes you can get away with Asp.Net just grumbling about it, but in this case it produces a runtime error.

Comment: You din't ask for that (selective html), what is in active veiw defined as html is visible, end of story (if view 1 is active title 1 is visble, and so on ). You might consider using an update panel for that

Comment: @SilentTremor - sorry confused you - by 'selective html' I meant the view - if you look at the code in the post you'll see what I mean.

Comment: You need to hide view's or even placeholders inside view's based on the active one.